No se ejecuta mi aplicación .NET MAUI en Windows10 x64
Cuando intento ejecutar mi aplicación de .NET MAUI desde Visual Studio (Visual Studio Community 2022) para windows me da un error:

Y ya esta habilitada la implementación y todo, incluso en la plataforma le especifique que era x64 (estoy en Win 10 x64) y antes estaba en Any CPU y aun así me salía el mismo mensaje de error.

Apenas estoy empezando en MAUI pero ya busque y verifique que todo estuviera correcto para ejecutar el proyecto en la misma maquina, porque en el emulador de Android si se ejecuta bien pero no me deja en la compu.

Habilite el modo de desarrollador de la maquina
Habilite lo del Hiper-V
El SDK esta actualizado
El Visual Studio esta actualizado

Hasta le pregunta a ChatGPT y me dijo lo mismo, que verificara que estuviera instalado el SDK de .NET MAUI y que estuviera actualizado Visual Studio, hasta reinicie Visual Studio y la compu y aun así hasta al día siguiente sigue igual, no se que más hacer.
Agrego el código que esta en el archivo .csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

    <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
    The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
    When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
    The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
    either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
    <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>PhoneWord</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>PhoneWord</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.phoneword</ApplicationId>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup></Project>

(Puse el </Project> a un lado de </ItemGroup> porque no se veía aquí pero en el archivo esta abajo, aunque ya se que no afecta pero aun así)
En este archivo no le moví nada, solo lo revise para ver las diferentes plataforma que estaban.

Abre el nombreproyecto.csproj con el bloq de notas, y agrega lo que sale a tu pregunta

Prueba cambiar los 2 primeros TargetFrameworks por <TargetFrameworks>WINDOWS</TargetFrameworks> 

@Yussef si lo pongo así como dices no me deja ni compilarlo, y también salen como advertencias en las dependencias
